# Mechanism to automatically HTML escape variable output in Classic ASP?

Tags: html, security, asp-classic, xss

Is there a way to automatically HTML escape output in an ASP template, in the same way Django or Jinja2 templates can?

Example:

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
```

And if `title = "<script>alert()</script>"`, the output is still `<h1>&lt;script&gt;alert()&lt;/script&gt;`.

My objective is to avoid needing to litter `Server.HtmlEncode()` everywhere.

Comment: I guess my question would be why do you need to `Server.HtmlEncode()` *"everywhere"*? Sound more like an issue with how you are trying to use ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an easy way to do this in classic ASP unfortunately. There is no built in tag to do html encoding automatically as far as I know.

You can use Server.HTMLEncode() and Server.URLEncode(), or you can make custom functions like h() and u() to just call these and at least make it shorter, but that's about it I think. Also be aware that when writing into a javascript context, these are not adequate, and there is no proper javascript string encoder in ASP for things like

```
<script>
  var x = <%= myVar %>;
</script>
```

It's tough to retrofit security in ASP (I suppose that's what you are after).

Answer (score -3):

```
<%=...%>
```

...is a way of injecting ASP values into your HTML document...

My understanding is that they can't be used within an ASP section:
    <%...%>

What you need is:

```
<% ASP script that gets variables %>
<html><body>
<h1><%= ASP_variable %></h1>
```

I'm also not clear why you seem to be trying to introduce a script into a Heading element.

Comment: Hang on! - you've just changed the question the moment I answered ...
But I'm still pretty sure you can't introduce a script like that from ASP into HTML. The script tag needs to be within the document to start with, and secondly, I don't think you can interrupt an element by suddenly introducing javascript. I suspect document.write() is what may help you - you can then inject ASP variables into the javascript.

Comment: Sorry but that is utter nonsense, server-side code is processed at the server before anything is returned to the browser it can manipulate anything, it has no constraints on what the client eventually sees.

Comment: @TonyDuffill: I think the OP is specifically *not* wanting to "introduce a script into a Heading element" - i.e. he's generating a page based on user input, and he doesn't trust said user input to not contain security holes like random script elements. If (when) he encounters such data, he wants to just display it on the page, instead of writing it to the page in such a way that it'll end up executing.

Comment: @Martha that's a whole lot of conjecture and guess work seen as though the OP doesn't mention anything like that. You usually use quotes around text to quote someone but the OP doesn't mention anywhere in the question "introduce a script into a Heading element"?? I suppose you can assume the XXS tag means that but still guess work nonetheless.

Comment: @Lankymart: I was quoting Tony.

Comment: @Martha fair enough, sorry I missed that.

Comment: @Lankymart - yes, sorry, I had a brain-fade on that one - the original question got changed the moment I answered it, and I ended up trying to answer a question that hadn't been asked. My fault entirely - apologies for confusing the issue.